# How to apply masonry after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry, buddypress

After clicking "Load More" in "Activity Page" of "BuddyPress", I want to apply "Masonry.js" to the activity list.

I wrote the following code for that, but `$ grid.masonry` after clicking "Load More" don't work.

```
(function($){

    if($('#activity-stream').length){

        var observer = new MutationObserver(function (MutationRecords, MutationObserver) {

            var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({ 
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                isFitWidth: true,
                isAnimated: true,
                columnWidth: 620,
            }); 

            $grid.masonry(); // don't work
            $grid.masonry('reloadItems'); // don't work
            $grid.masonry('layout'); // don't work

        });

        observer.observe($('#activity-stream').get(0), {
            childList: true,
        });

    }

})(jQuery);
```

If I add elements such as `span` and use `settimeout` as shown below, "Masonry.js" will work, but this is inappropriate.

```
(function($){

    if($('#activity-stream').length){

        $('body').on("click",'.load-more',function(){
            $('#activity-stream').prepend('<span></span>');
        }); 

        var observer = new MutationObserver(function (MutationRecords, MutationObserver) {

            var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({ 
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                isFitWidth: true,
                isAnimated: true,
                columnWidth: 620,
            }); 

            setTimeout(function(){
                $grid.masonry();
                $grid.masonry('reloadItems');
                $grid.masonry('layout');
            },5000);    

        });

        observer.observe($('#activity-stream').get(0), {
            childList: true,
        });

    }

})(jQuery);
```

I'm totally lost in life and don't know what to do...

It would be greatly appreciated if you could explain the details.

Thanks.

Masonry.js:https://github.com/desandro/masonry

Comment: There is an example of load more inside documentation https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/kwsJb , I hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When You've completed Your elements adding to the DOM (maybe with an AJAX call), then call the `.layout()` method on Your **Masonry instance**. Do not initialize Mansory more than once and do it at the Document Ready Event. See https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html
- If You can post the page, with the HTML maybe I can qualify my
  answer, it depends on the Wordpress theme used.
- It should be possible that the definition of the Observer is been
  executed after the AJAX call so the Mutation is not detected

---